# Can we use "at the cost of" to express equality of the prices?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, prepositional-phrases

I want to say you can buy, for example, three e-books buy exactly the same amount of money which you have to pay to buy a single paper book; Is it correct to say it like this?

> You can buy, for example, three e-books **at the cost of** a single paper book?

If yes, is it idiomatic or there are better ways to express it?

Answer (score 5):

I would say that it's *not* correct. "At the cost of" normally indicates what one *loses*. (In your sentence, you don't lose the physical book by buying the e-books; you just lose some money that could instead have been used to buy a physical book.) And what's more, "at the cost of" is *usually* figurative, rather than denoting an actual purchase or exchange; for example, "He achieved his goal, but at the cost of his health" means that his health suffered as a result of his pursuit of his goal.

Instead, you can either say "for the price of" or (as skullpatrol suggests) you can use the word *same*: "for the same price as", "for the same cost as", "at the same cost as", etc. (Personally, I still find *price* preferable, but *cost* is quite correct.)

(The preposition *at* can also be used with *price*, but in this case it would make it sound like there is a specific price for a set of three e-books. To use *at* with *price*, you would need to rework the sentence a bit: "You can buy an e-book at [*or* for] one-third the price of a paper book.")

Comment: Will it be easier to grasp as compared to 'one-third the price of'  if one says that he bought three e-books for the price of one paper book?

Comment: I've just recollected that there is an expression "at cost price" i.e. one buys books at cost price, but not at selling price. The cost price is composed of costs incurred by a seller to produce a product. I wonder whether 'at the cost of' somehow means the cost price.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this answer. I thought the O.P.'s original wording was understandable and idiomatic. That said, I agree with the suggested improvements – I just don't know if I'd go so far as to deem the original "not correct". Also, [the word _cost_ **can** be used for _price_](http://www.onelook.com/?w=cost); I don't agree that it "normally indicates what one loses."

Comment: @snail - I think both words can be used in both ways. (For example: _They won the battle, but at a terrible price._) Of course we can use _cost_ for abstract things like health – but it's not limited to that usage.

Comment: +1 for 'at the cost of' being a negative exchange. "He got his degree, at the cost of his social life" rather than 'at the cost of his spare time', which would have been the 'direct' price he paid.

Comment: @J.R. Maybe the word 'cost' can stand for price if it is used without the preposition 'of'. E.g. I was able to buy the damaged goods at cost (= for only the amount of money needed to produce or get the goods, without any extra money added for profit). //Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: I would not say that 'at the cost of' implies that someone loses something. Can 'at the cost of' be synonymous with 'in exchange for' or 'at expense of' or 'on account of'?

Comment: @Humbulani - Those are valid ways the word _cost_ can be used, but it can also be used with _of_, when speaking of prices. [Here are some examples](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22at+a+cost+of+*%22&safe=off&start=10).

Comment: @J.R.: I agree that *cost* can mean *price*; but I don't agree that "at the cost of _____" can mean "for the same cost as _____". Firstly -- I checked your link, and in all cases, the _____ denoted what was lost. (Contrast this with the OP's example, where the _____ denotes something *else* that would have had the *same* cost.) Secondly -- your link is actually "at **a** cost of _____". I think this is significant; "at the cost of" is an idiom that tends to drive out alternative would-have-been-plausible senses.

Comment: @ruakh - I see what you're saying, now that you've edited your answer. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

> You can buy, for example, three e-books **at the cost of** a single paper book.

means "If you have a single paper book, you can trade it for three e-books."

The following sentence means what you intended:

> You can buy, for example, three e-books **for the cost of** a single paper book.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you can

> buy three e-books **for the same price as** one paper book

but your wording does make sense.